# How to determine if ASAM is enabled?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to be able to determine if it's safe to attempt to enable ASAM mode. To determine this, it would be helpful if I could tell if SAM is enable, or ASAM is already enabled, or, in general, which Single App Mode is enabled on the device (whether it's regular Guided Access, SAM, or ASAM).

When ASAM or SAM is enabled, `UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled()` returns `false`, so that function appears to be unhelpful in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. There is no way to determine whether it's SAM, ASAM, or Guided Access.

I could not find any way, and no one has answered in 6 months.